# How can I see why a dependency was installed in npm?

Tags: javascript, npm

This is probably a duplicate, but I can't find the answer anywhere using search.

I believe NPM has a command like

```
npm why module-name
```

Or

```
npm explain module-name
```

That explains why a dependency was installed, eg, which modules in `package.json` use it. **How can I see why a dependency was installed in npm?**

Comment: see `package-lock.json`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
npm ls circular-json

`-- eslint@5.9.0
`-- file-entry-cache@2.0.0
    `-- flat-cache@1.3.4
    `-- circular-json@0.3.3
```

`npm ls` will show you your package dependencies in tree form. You will be able to identify and trace down to see exactly which packages depend on what.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. Will accept it once time limit is up.

Comment: great! glad to help :)